# In XSLT, how can I get the value of a nodeset parameter inside my template?

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT template which defines a parameter like this:

```
<xsl:param name="weight"/>
```

I call it like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="MakeBlock">
  <xsl:with-param name="weight" select="normal"/>
  [...]
```

Inside my template, I try to use the `$weight` parameter like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="font-weight">
 <xsl:copy-of select="$weight"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<fo:block font-weight="$weight"/>
```

In both cases, it's not rendering to the output.

When I debug in Visual Studio and stop on a breakpoint, then show the value of the `$weight` parameter, I get this as its value:

```
{Dimension:[0]}
```

My understanding of this is that the parameter is a nodeset of some kind.  So, I have tried this to "get at" its value:

```
exsl:node-set($weight)/
```

I have Googled quite a bit and found a bunch of examples which tell me that should work.  And yes, I have handled the namespace like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl" [other stuff...] />
```

How do I use this parameter inside my template?  (I am using the default XSLT 1.0 transform inside C#, if that matters.)

**Edit:**

Here is the full template:

```
<xsl:template name="MakeBlock">     
  <xsl:param name="font-size"/>
  <xsl:param name="font-family"/>
  <xsl:param name="weight"/>
  <xsl:param name="space-after"/>
  <xsl:param name="content"/>
  <fo:block font-weight="{$weight}" font-size="{$font-size}pt" font-family="{$font-family}" space-after="{$space-after}pt">
    <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

And here is how it's called:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:call-template name="MakeBlock">
    <xsl:with-param name="font-size" select="11"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="font-family">PT Sans</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="weight" select="normal"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="space-after" select="11"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="content">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the `space-after` and `font-size` params work fine, but the `font-weight` and `font-family` params both have the problem I note above.  I'm guessing it has something to do with how string params are handled vs. numeric params?

Comment: As always, please show a [minimal, but complete and verifiable sample of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For XSLT questions, this typically means an input XML sample, a complete XSLT stylesheet and the output XML you expect. Thanks! (Finally, tag XSLT questions with either `xslt-1.0` or `xslt-2.0`.)

Comment: Can you show us the XML input  and XSLT context, as well as the result you want? With `<xsl:with-param name="weight" select="normal"/>` you select the `normal` child element(s) of the context node, as you then seem to want to construct an attribute doing `xsl:copy-of` does not make sense as you can't put an element into an attribute. So `<xsl:value-of select="$weight"/>` would make more sense.

Comment: Edited to provide the requested code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a literal string value then you need `<xsl:with-param name="weight" select="'normal'"/>`.

Comment: Wow. Okay, I had no idea.  For my own education -- by not including the single quotes, what exactly was I passing, and how would I get at that?

Comment: @Deane You were passing an element node from the input called `normal`,  more precisely a child of the context node.

Comment: As I said in my comment, with `<xsl:with-param name="weight" select="normal"/>` you select the `normal` child element(s) of the context node, which only makes sense if your context node has child elements named `normal`. Your would then select the parameter value also with `$weight`, but in your case as there are no such child elements you are outputting an empty node-set.

Comment: This further makes sense -- the `with-param` calls that were just numbers (`font-weight` and `space-after') were passed as literals since XML elements can't begin with a number. Since a number would be invalid as a selector, the engine helpfully assumed I wanted a string literal, thus those two worked as I expected.

Comment: XPath 1.0 expressions can be of type number, string, boolean and node-set. So `select="11"` is simply a `select` attribute with an expression of type number, a number literal in that case. A string literal is written with quotes as a delimiter, e.g. `'normal'` or `"normal"`. See the XPath spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Expressions. If you want a string literal in C# you also need to write `"normal"` while a number literal is simply written without any delimiters as well in that language.